# Classification with feed forward network in Matlab strange results?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron

I have ran some classification tests in Matlab with feed forward network. Using the standard `tansig` function the results were better when using more neurons on the hidden layer.
But, when I switched to `pure lin` I was surprised to see that the results were better when I set a smaller number of neurons on the hidden layer. 
Can you help me with an argument for these situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tansig` activation function essentially makes it possible than a neuron becomes inactive due to saturation. A linear neuron is always active. Therefore if one linear neuron has bad parameters, it will always affect the outcome of the classification. A higher number of neurons yield a higher probability of bad behavior in this scenario.